# iOS dev: why the scrollView is null

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an e-pub app, and want to use UIScrollView to display multiple pages. But I found the scrollView variable is null after the viewDidLoad is called by viewing thru breakpoint. The code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PagedScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
@implementation PagedScrollViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;

@synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
@synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     NSLog(@"paged view did load");

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Paged";
```

And I found the scrollView is still set to null after viewDidload.
In previous view I am using below code to switch to above view:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"touch pressed");
    PagedScrollViewController *indexView = [[PagedScrollViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:indexView animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"touch pressed 2");
}
```

Comment: Have you linked your scrollView in the xib file?

Comment: definitely this is mapping problem of IBOutlet...

Comment: from above code it seems that no problem in code.must be mapping problem in xib.Make sure....:)

Answer (score 2):

IBOutlets that are nil are almost always caused by a broken outlet link in IB (Interface Builder). Open the VC in IB, select the "connection inspector" and then click on the scroll view. See if it is connected to an IBOutlet in your VC. IF not, control-drag from the scroll view onto "file's owner" and select the "scrollView" outlet to make the connection.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your xib file scroll view outlet is connected to `scrollView` in your .h file.

Also some comments about your code:

1. make your `IBOutlet` properties `weak` instead of `strong`. you could have retain problems if you don't.
2. you don't need the `@synthesize` statements if you're using a recent version of Xcode and targeting iO 5+.

EDIT:

Look at your `PagedScrollViewController.xib` file and check that the Referencing Outlet for `scrollView` is connected. See this screenshot of where to do that in Interface Builder - like the `view` outlet shown. @duncan-c gives a good description on how to hook it up too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I have connected the outlet as you can see the first part of code in my post. Anything I am wrong?

Comment: See my edit to verify that your scroll view is connected in Interface Builder.